# why selected part used in code for finding sum of positive element of an array?

Tags: java

I have this code :

```
class Gauss {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ia = new int[101];
        for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++)
            ia[i] = i;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++)
            sum += ia[i];
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

This java code tries to find out the sum of positive elements of an array. I understood the way it is implemented but am not clear about this part,

```
class Gauss {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ia = new int[101];
        for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++)
            ia[i] = i;
}
```

Why is this part used here?

Comment: It fills the int array with values.

Comment: That `for` loop is just used to populate the initial values of the array. It's not part of the summation. Is that what's confusing you?

Comment: i knew its not for summation,  but wasn't sure about its uses . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the for part is used to initialise ia array with  0 to 100 values.

by default every ia[i] element will be 0.

becuase of this loop you array gets values

```
ia[0] =0
ia[1] =1
ia[2] =2
ia[3] =3
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This part populates the array. The element at index 0 has the value 0, the element at index 1 has the value 1, etc. until the index 100 (included). Without this part, all the elements would have the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This creates an array of ints of size 101
    int[] ia = new int[101];
//This is a for-loop (that will continue for as long as i<ia.length) that fills
//the array with the value of i. i will increase +1 in value every time it loops
    for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++)
        ia[i] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++)
    ia[i] = i;

this part initializing the array with values from 0 to 100.
Then adding this values in next part. Probably the task is to
add numbers from 0 to 100.